# Most useful MSVC++ non-standard macros

Tags: visual-c++, preprocessor

The standard includes macros line _____LINE_____ & _____FILE_____, and C99 adds _____FUNCTION_____ which is technically not part of C++ yet.

What additional ones does MSVC++ add which are useful/cool? I found _____FUNCTION_____ is supported but are there any other totally MS-specific ones worth knowing about?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665537/how-to-find-out-cl-exes-built-in-macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN has a list of all of the [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.100).aspx) used by Visual C++.

The most widely used is arguably `_WIN32`, which can be used for conditionally including Windows-specific headers and functionality in cross-platform software.

`_MSC_VER` defines the compiler version number and is useful if you need to rely on functionality introduced in a more recent version of the compiler or need to work around a bug that existed in an older version.