# Visual C++ dump preprocessor defines

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to find out all the preprocessor defines of the [Visual C++ compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_versions) (MSVC). I can do

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

on GCC to dump all the preprocessor defines. Do we have something similar with the Visual C++ compiler compiler?

I'm using [Visual C++ 9.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out cl.exe's builtuin macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665537/how-to-find-out-cl-exes-builtuin-macros)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out cl.exe's built-in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665537/how-to-find-out-cl-exes-built-in-macros)

Answer (score 5):

There is no such command. However, [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) (both online and offline) [lists all the preprocessor defines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros), both Microsoft specific, standard defined and ANSI defines.