# How to get all Macros of a C++ project using Visual Studio Professional 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Can anybody tell me how to

1. Get all macros of a C++ project, or
2. If above is impossible, check if a project contains some macro, say, MACRO_X?
3. I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012 on Windows 7, so, preferrably, tools involve only those avialable in this environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course this is possible. The pre-processor in a C++ compiler does almost exactly this, except rather than notify you that the macro is there, they do the substitution. So all you need to do is write a pre-processor that notifies instead of substituting.

Comment: AFAIK in ObjectBrowser (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbs280h1.aspx) you can browse macros too. You can also use command line tool :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87x7wc99.aspx But - I am not sure - I do not have visual studio installed...

Comment: You could set search scope to "Entire project" and search for "#define"

Comment: @Logicrat: That would miss all macros defined in 3rd party header files, or those defined on the command line.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74592316/1147688).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS, I assume you're using this on Windows with the MSVC `cl` compiler, in which case you can get all C++ macros (from Developer Powershell) with:

```
echo // > foo.cpp; cl /nologo /Zc:preprocessor /PD /EHs /TP foo.cpp |sort; rm foo.cpp, foo.obj
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (a starting point):

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null >
/<pathFileName>/gcc_predefined_macros.txt
```

On an earlier version of my system, it produced 450+ items.  I have not found a way to confirm.

g++ 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10 reports 241 predefined macros ... I think most of the reduction is duplicate removal.  I still have not found a mechanism to confirm.

But, I suppose this does not get user defined macros nor command line, either.

Comment: That's for gcc, not VS `cl`.