# How do you email to a userlist in CL?

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

Like the name implies. I need to modify a variety of programs to email reports to userlists where they are hardcoded to send to certain users, a large amount are clles. Basically, what is the syntax for userlist functionality in cl?

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: I don't know what else I would ask for. I just need some example syntax for a userlist.

Comment: For instance, what is "cl"? I'm pretty sure you're not talking about the C++ compiler and linker.

Comment: Well than you have to search for an example. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665537/how-to-find-out-cl-exes-built-in-macros

Comment: I'm talking about clle (ILE control language (CL) programs). Similar to CLP. I program primarily in rpgle and rpg free.

Comment: See, that might be a good start, rather than using just the initials of an obscure language, without at any point specifying the technology you're using, and tagging it with a tag for a *different* technology with the same initials.

Comment: How are you sending email in your CLP program? Are you using the SNDDST command?  Using a 3rd party product?

Comment: I suspect if you could define your problem you'd be close to your answer

Comment: Thanks for the lecture Avner. It's a .clle file written in RDi as part of an AS400 mod 8 database. Currently, it's hardcoded like so:

Comment: DCL        VAR(&EMAIL1) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(40) +
                          VALUE('EMAIL@.COM')

Comment: IF         COND(&RECORDS *GT 0) THEN(DO)
             IF         COND(&EMAIL1 *NE ' ') THEN(DO)
             CALL       PGM(RHPEMAIL) PARM(&EMAIL1 'PGMNAME' +
                          'PGMNAME' &SUBJECT)
             ENDDO
             IF         COND(&EMAIL2 *EQ ' ') THEN(DO)
             CHGVAR     VAR(&EMAIL2) VALUE('EMAIL@.COM')
             ENDDO

Comment: So RHPEMAIL is the program being called to send the mail?  I would suggest contacting whoever wrote that program to find out how to use it.

Comment: I just ask an email tech support person to create a "distro" then treat it like an ordinary email address.

Answer (score 2):

The basic command to emaill is this...

```
SNDSMTPEMM RCP((mydl@mycomp.com)) +            
             SUBJECT(&SUBJECT) NOTE(&NOTE) +        
             ATTACH((&ATTACH *EXCEL)) CONTENT(*HTML)
```

For a professional business email you need to send from a distribution list so replies to the email go to the distribution list not to noreply@somewhere.com

1. Create the cl that is doing the emailing with *OWNER authority
2. Create a user profile "myuser" to be used for the emailing.
3. Create an alias for "myuser" with WRKNAMSMTP

User ID/Address . . . . . :   myuser   msystem

SMTP user ID  . . . . . . :   mydl
SMTP domain . . . . . . . :   mydomain.COM

then submit the CL for the user myuser.  it will appear as if coming from the distribution list and replies will go to the distribution list.

```
SBMJOB     CMD(CALL PGM(myemailc) PARM(&mparm1 &mparm2)) +
             JOB(myemailc) JOBD(mylib/myjobd) +            
             JOBQ(qsysnomax) USER(myuser)
```