# Why Visual Studio Code can't find the `ulong/uint` even if the header file path is in the include path?

Tags: mysql, c, visual-studio-code, include, include-path

I'm trying to make Intellisense work on the MySQL source code, using Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu.

The project requires `libmysqlclient-dev`, which is installed.

Even though I include the development headers path in the `includePath`:

```
        "includePath": [
            "/usr/include/mysql",
            "${workspaceFolder}/include"
        ],
```

(this is a part of the includes required; I've added many others to no avail)

the data types `ulong` and `uint` are not recognized, causing a flurry of errors:

```
identifier "uint" is undefined
identifier "ulong" is undefined
// and so on
```

This is strange, since I can see both types defined:

```
/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h
177:typedef unsigned int uint;
497:typedef unsigned long   ulong;        /* Short for unsigned long */
504:typedef unsigned long long int ulonglong; /* ulong or unsigned long long */
```

And the include directive is present (example file follows):

```
client/mysqldump.c
43:#include <my_global.h>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Make a backup copy of `my_global.h`, and then insert a `#error line177` before line 177. See if you actually get there.

Comment: *I can see both types defined*  Except you don't know that you get past the myriad `#ifdef`'s to actually reach those lines.

Comment: thanks both! I'm new to C (I come from languages without ifdef), and in fact, the problem is that the `typedef`s are surrounded by `#if`.

Comment: If any of you posts this as answer, I'll mark it as answered!

Comment: I'll let @AndrewHenle take the points, if he wishes to.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks - it's not a very specific answer, but I hope it works.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Has some good info in it. Better than I would have done.

Comment: @user3386109 Now I won't feel guilty.  :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the complex use of conditional compilation features such as `#if`, `#ifdef`, and `#ifndef` in the source code (a version is available [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/8.0.0/my__global_8h_source.html)), without specific information on your exact environment, it's impossible to say *exactly* what you need to do.

But, in general, you need to make sure your environment is such that the lines with the relevant `typedef` statements are actually included by the C preprocessor in the code that is compiled.

There are several ways to help determine that.  One, you can have your compiler dump all its macros.  For MSVC, see [How to find out cl.exe's built-in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665537/how-to-find-out-cl-exes-built-in-macros).  Second, you can examine the output of the preprocessed code.  For MSVC see [How do I see a C/C++ source file after preprocessing in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio).

Either of those can be of great assistance in seeing what code is actually getting compiled when there are many possible results because of complex `#if...` preprocessor directives.